# Can't load image from props

Tags: react-native, redux

Somehow the location of my image is not found load it from props.

This works

```
let overview_bg = require('../../images/locaties/placeholder.png');
<Image source={overview_bg} style={styles.overview_bg}>
```

But when I get the url from props it doesn't:

```
let overview_bg = require(this.props.image);
<Image source={overview_bg} style={styles.overview_bg}>
```

`this.props.image` has the exact same url which gives me the error:

> Requiring unknown module "../../images/locaties/placeholder.png". If
>   you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or
>   running "npm install"

I have checked the url multiple times it is exactly the same. I also tested it in `console.log`

The prop is given from another container which gets it from the store.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the extension in the first example

Comment: Also, the value I get from the store is an ajax value which is stored in redux-persist. I'm not sure if this can have anything to do with it since it's already persisted and the error I get knows that the value is the exact url that I need.

Comment: As pointed out by David, require() only works for static resources. Probably you would need to pass in require('something.jpg') as props.image then directly set <Image source={this.props.image}/>

Comment: var overview_bg = require(this.props.image);
Try this to include

Answer (score 0):

From the [React Native Image documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html):

> Note that in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```